# Angular8 - FormGroup setValue only if string is not empty

Tags: angular, angular8, form-control, formgroups

In my project, I have several `FormControls`:

**app.component.ts**

```
  readonly titleCtrl = new FormControl()
  readonly descriptionCtrl = new FormControl()
  readonly ageCtrl = new FormControl(null)
```

which I've added to a `FormGroup`:

```
  readonly formGroup = new FormGroup({
    title: this.titleCtrl,
    description: this.descriptionCtrl,
    age: this.ageCtrl,
  })
```

and then store in my Mongo DB:

```
private fillForm(item: Item): void {
  this.formGroup.setValue(
    {
      title: item.title.overrideValue,
      description: item.description.overrideValue,
      age: item.age.overrideValue,
    },
    { emitEvent: false },
  )
}
```

So everything works fine and it stores my values in the DB. But it also stores empty values in the DB. What should I do that this isn't possible?

If a user edits e.g. the `title` this function stores it in the DB as `title.overrideValue` which is ok. But if the user edits the title again and deletes the value (so the `title` is an empty string), it should take the `title.sourceValue`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
private fillForm(item: Item): void {
  this.formGroup.setValue(
    {
      title: item.title.overrideValue ?  item.title.overrideValue :  item.title.sourceValue,
      description: item.description.overrideValue,
      age: item.age.overrideValue,
    },
    { emitEvent: false },
  )
}
```

The `?` in `item.title.overrideValue ?  item.title.overrideValue :  item.title.sourceValue` is called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and basically is a one-line if-statement. 
If `item.title.overrideValue` is equal to `""` or `undefined` it will use the `sourceValue` otherwise the `overrideValue`

Other things you could try, is to prevent empty input (via Validators). The Angular Docs offer an [example](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validator-functions) for that.

Comment: thanks. This solution works not 100%. If overrideValue is now empty, it displays the sourceValue which is ok. but if I delete the value in the form, I'm able to save it and it store still a empty string in the DB

Comment: You need to verfiy the form before sending it then. 

In the method where you send it, just check all fields and replace if necessary, if you can post the the sending method aswell I can help you further.

Comment: this `setValue` is where I send it. So normally `overrideValue` is empty and the `sourceValue` is never empty. So it should only take it when there is really a value written in this input field. otherwise it could be empty

Comment: at the moment, when `overrideValue` is `null` it also takes the `sourceValue` but if a user edits the title and deletes the value, its not `null` its "".

Comment: So you mean when `item.title.overrideValue` equals `""` it still gets used? Because in javascript/typescript `""` should default to `false` and therefore should use the righthandside of the ternary.

Comment: Yes, equals "" is still used, but it should be `null`

Comment: I could not exactly understand what you mean, Do you want `""` to be displayed as `null` instead of the `sourceValue`?

Answer (score 0):

use validators for your formGroup as:

```
readonly formGroup = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(this.titleCtrl, Validators.required),
    description: this.descriptionCtrl,
    age: this.ageCtrl,
  });
```

then, you can use custom getter for each form field and customize the validation message:

```
  get titleFormControl() { return this.formGroup.get('titleFormControl'); }
  get titleFormControlErrorMessage() {
    if (this.titleFormControl.hasError('required')) {
      return 'Title is required';
    }

    return '';
  }
```

and in your template:

```
<span *ngIf="titleFormControl.invalid">{{titleFormControlErrorMessage}}</span>
```

Anyway, any clientside validation (angular) must be duplicated in your server api. Shortly, in your server, check again if the field is empty and throw an exception if yes.